# Value of <input> created via DOM is not submitted

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I am working on front-end editting and got this line of code

```
<span onclick="var input = document.createElement('input'); input.setAttribute('value', this.firstChild.nodeValue); input.setAttribute('name', 'ac'); input.setAttribute('onblur', 'document.getElementById(\'front11\').submit();'); this.parentNode.replaceChild(input, this);">2015104015</span>
```

This results in this line

```
<input value="2014102016" name="ac" onblur="document.getElementById('front11').submit();">
```

The complete form looks like this after the DOM change

```
<form id="front11" action="/index.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="3394" />
<input value="2014102016" name="ac" onblur="document.getElementById('front11').submit();">
</form>
```

The form is correctly submitted, but ONLY 'id' submitted, not 'ac'. Any thoughts?

Comment: If the element is being added to the DOM, use Inspect Element to make sure it has all the attributes it should. And please consider not using so much inline code if you can help it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the **`type`**

Set it as

```
<input type="text" value="2014102016" name="ac" onblur="document.getElementById('front11').submit();">
```

Comment: Type defaults to text, however I did add it to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Split things out and see what your error console says at this point:

(BTW: setAttribute isn't exactly broken but it really really doesn't do what everyone thinks it does.  Attributes and properties are two different things -- that's why there are two different names.)

**Warning: Typed off-the-cuff**

```
<script>
function do_it(el) {
  function submitIt() {
    this.form.submit();
  }

  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.value = this.firstChild.nodeValue;
  input.name = 'ac';
  input.onblur = submitIt;    
  el.parentNode.replaceChild(input, el);"
}
</script>

<span onclick="do_it(this)">2015104015</span>
```